# Epmd is not shared between docker with --net option

Tags: docker, erlang, elixir, epmd

I was trying to understand a little more about the [epmd](http://erlang.org/doc/man/epmd.html) and playing with docker.

My idea was to run two dockers using `--net=host` options like this:

```
docker run -i -t --net=host elixir iex --sname node1 --cookie cookie
docker run -i -t --net=host elixir iex --sname node2 --cookie cookie
```

I was expecting the `epmd` only to be launched in the first docker since the second one should realize that there is already a `epmd` running on port 4369, but my surprise was that the `epmd` service was up in both of the dockers.

So, is this the expected behavior? Should one of the epmd server to be off?